# Repeatedly altering visibility of a child view and measuring parent view causes wrong results in measured size and display

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-viewgroup, android-measure

Why is it that when you repeatedly alter the visibility of a child view that is contained within a parent view and measure the parent view, Android returns wrong results?

I created a simple test: an XML file with only one ConstraintLayout and two TextViews. I will repeatedly alter the visibility of the last TextView to GONE and VISIBLE. Each time I alter the visibility of the TextView, I will measure the ConstraintLayout's width and height. To alter the visibility of the TextView, I set a click listener on the ConstraintLayout.

Here's the XML for said simple layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/testLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iWillShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textColor="@color/colorOnPrimary"/>

    // This one will be hidden on click
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hideMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="World"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iWillShow"
        android:textColor="@color/colorOnPrimary" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In my Kotlin file, I have the following:

```
testLayout.setOnClickListener {
    val matchParentMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((it.parent as View).width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    val wrapContentMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    hideMe.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    it.measure(matchParentMeasureSpec, wrapContentMeasureSpec)
    Log.d("TEST LAYOUT", it.measuredWidth.toString() + " " + it.measuredHeight.toString())
    hideMe.visibility = View.GONE
    it.measure(matchParentMeasureSpec, wrapContentMeasureSpec)
    Log.d("TEST LAYOUT", it.measuredWidth.toString() + " " + it.measuredHeight.toString())
    hideMe.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    it.measure(matchParentMeasureSpec, wrapContentMeasureSpec)
    Log.d("TEST LAYOUT", it.measuredWidth.toString() + " " + it.measuredHeight.toString())
    hideMe.visibility = View.GONE
    it.measure(matchParentMeasureSpec, wrapContentMeasureSpec)
    Log.d("TEST LAYOUT", it.measuredWidth.toString() + " " + it.measuredHeight.toString())
}
```

Upon clicking the parent view, the logs will return exactly these:

```
D/TEST LAYOUT: 1080 186
D/TEST LAYOUT: 1080 135
D/TEST LAYOUT: 1080 186
D/TEST LAYOUT: 1080 186
```

Obviously, the above logs are incorrect. It should have returned `D/TEST LAYOUT: 1080 135` on the last line. However, that doesn't seem to be the case. Furthermore, it also caused an erroneous display. The height of the parent view will be the following (**this is wrong, it should have been smaller**):

[image: Incorrect Height]

When I tried only setting the visibility of the TextView to GONE without the measuring (like this):

```
testLayout.setOnClickListener {
    hideMe.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

It returns the correct display of height like below:

[image: Correct Height]

Why does the above happen? What's the process behind it? The problem occurs after setting GONE -> VISIBLE once. After one occurrence of setting GONE -> VISIBLE, setting it to GONE -> VISIBLE -> GONE ... will produce that error.

Comment: Deleted my answer. The first flip from visible to gone and vice versa always work in my limited testing. This is true even with a gone margin, so I think that my hypothesis about needing a layout as part of the underlying design is incorrect although layouts do resolve the issue.

Comment: @Cheticamp I see. Nevertheless, thanks for the effort to answer! I hope that you or someone else can provide another explanation as to why this is happening.

Comment: Can anyone please help?